# Best practice for creating javascript shared class with methods to be called in html

Tags: javascript, html

There are several ways, I've realized, one can create (better say 'simulate') a javascript shared (static) class which contains a bunch of shared methods that can be called from html:

```
<html>
...
  <script>
  my_method_to_call
  </script>
...
</html>
```

What is the best practice I wonder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
    <script>
    var my_static_methods = {
        my_method_to_call_1 : function(){

        },
        my_method_to_call_2 : function(){

        }
    };
    </script>
```

and call them by

```
my_static_methods.my_method_to_call_1();
```

the same result can be achieved by doing

```
var My_static_methods = function(){
    this.my_method_to_call_1 = function(){

    };
    this.my_method_to_call_2 = function(){

    };
};
var my_static_methods = new My_static_methods();
```

Comment: Thanx. First solution seems to fit my needs the best.